# How to change App Store language display?

Tags: ios, app-store

I App Store my apps are declared as "English", but they‘re in German language.

How can I change the "App Store Language Display" from "English" to "German"?

I think I have to do this change in Xcode, right? But how can I do it? I hope for help. Have a nice day, David.

Comment: see this link may be helps you https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5012625

Comment: please check this link https://support.apple.com/en-in/HT201690

Comment: Both of the links don't help me. See this link: http://postimg.org/image/i35yzfbz5/ It should be "Language: German", not "Language: English". How to do it?

Answer (score 2):

This has to be changed in the code.

If your app is localized all supported languages will be listed here, if not look at the `Localization native development region`in your plist file